# What would the batch equivalent of Python's "pass" argument be?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm attempting to make a batch file that simplifies the command line just a little. The problem I'm running into is that, following an error check system I made, I don't want anything to happen with "else".

I need an equivalent to the `pass` argument that Python has; an argument that lets the interpreter know not to do anything and to wait until the next line with instructions is stated.

Is there a batch equivalent to this? If not, is there an easy way to do such a thing?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. What have you tried so far? Can you provide a code sample that is not doing what you expect/desire it to do? From your explanation, it sounds like you want to skip the `Else` portion of a conditional. If I'm understanding your need correctly, you won't need to do anything. Just leave out the `Else` portion -- it is optional.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I wanted to do.
Basically, in Python, if you need a part from a certain conditional or loop, the ``pass`` argument will do literally nothing and continue on, so that other if/then statements don't get mixed up in it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch doesn't have a real equivalent to python's `pass`, but it doesn't seem like you really need it here. If you don't want to do anything in the `else` clause, just omit this clause entirely. e.g.:

```
IF EXIST "somefile.txt" (
    ECHO "yay!"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A trivial solution is to use the `REM` command or `REM pass`.

As far as I know,  there is no equivalent of the'pass' command in Command Prompt.

If you really want a 'pass' command,  you could make your own. For instance,  take any "Hello, World!" example in your favourite programming language,  remove the print command and compile it to 'pass'. Put the output somewhere in your path and there you are.

Comment: So tl;dr, there's no *real* ``pass`` argument, and just commenting something using ``rem`` would work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pass in python use the goto and abuse it here. It was made for this. 
We'll setup a pass goto like this:

if blah
 echo "blah blah" goto :pass

:return
  echo "now we're here"

:pass echo "blah blah" goto :return

I see goto's spoken of as a no no by everyone and I say that's bull. They solve very complicated code problems if used right, and as long as you make sure they are all defined and used once only, they are very reliable. I know this is an old question but maybe it will help someone else.

Hoss